# Severity notice: Undefined variable - images_model

Tags: codeigniter, undefined-variable

This code works well in the "images" view under images_model:

```
<?php if($images_model):?>
    <?php foreach($images_model as $images):?>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="well">

                <img src="<?php echo base_url()."uploads/".$images->name;?>" alt="" class="img-thumbnail">
```

The code in images_model is the following:

```
function save_image($data){     
    $this->db->insert('images', $data);
}
```

When I try to use the same code in the "wall" view (main_controller) I get the severity notice error saying "images_model" is undefined; even though I load the images_model in the main_controller or auto-load the both models:

```
$autoload['model'] = array('main_model', 'images_model');
```

I originally questioned the "foreach" code in the "images" view, but I thought if it works in one view shouldn't it also work in another if I load the related model? It just doesn't seem to be reading the images_model.

I'm just getting to know codeigniter a bit and would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: change images_model to Images_model in all place.

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin thanks but it's not working. And if I change it in "images" view it gives me that error where before it was OK.

Comment: what is the new error?

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin undefined variable. Same error.

Comment: it must be like this `$autoload['model'] = array('Main_model', 'Images_model'); `and your file model name first leter must be uppercase and change your modal name in modal from `class images_model extends CI_Model` to  `class Images_model extends CI_Model`

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin "Images" is already capitalized in Images_model extends CI_Model. Capitalizing it in the "wall" view and autoload is giving the same undefined error.  

In the "images" view, capitalizing the "I" in all places works OK even as with the lower case "i" before (except for in the Model). 

Strange, right? Somehow the Main controller is not connecting with the Images_model to pass it to the view. Where as the Images controller is in sync with the Images_model and images view.

Comment: you can directly access `$this->some_model` in the view. just an fyi

Comment: @Alex. I'm aware of that and have used it. In loading the pictures though, the working code I have is using a "foreach" statement referencing the model. I think I've found a solution which I'll be trying. Will update this thread. Thanks for the input!

Comment: ah referencing the model function result i suppose. yea, just weird variable naming threw me off. thought you were trying to pass the model via a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you passing the $images_model variable to your view from your main_controller ?

```
// Set your variable
$data['images_model'] = $images_model;

// Pass variable to view
$this->load->view('main', $data);
```

You typically shouldn't have access to a model directly in the view (following MVC principals). Your controller should get what it wants from the model, then pass it to the view.

Comment: Erick, getting undefined images_model with your new line of codes I added below . The view you reference would be the "wall" under the main_controller. Good point though which I thought would resolve it. But I'll keep checking. Thanks!     
                         
public function index($page='wall') {                                     
              
              
              $data = $this->session->userdata;

              $data['images_model'] = $images_model;
              
                          
              $this->load->view($page, $data);
              
    }